# "As long as" for "since" in AE

Tags: grammar, american-english, vocabulary, word-usage, colloquialisms

Some of you might have noticed that I oftentimes use the conjunction "as long as" in my questions and my posts.

I was just wondering -- does "as long as" in the sense "since" [=in view of the fact that, considering, inasmuch as] have any currency in AE, and can it be used just about safely for whatever register of language but the most formal prose?

You might want to consider the following sources and examples for this:

> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/as+long+as
>
> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20long%20as
>
> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/since

As long as (= since/inasmuch as) you're not interested, I won't tell you about it.

As long as (= since/inasmuch as) you're already here, you might as well stay.

As long as (= since/inasmuch as) you have offered, I accept.

As long as you've offered your daughter the possibility for information and she's stated her preference, there's no reason to insist.

As long as you've provided her with the opportunity to learn, it's best that you wait for indications of her readiness... [source](https://www.creators.com/advice/sylvia-rimm-on-raising-kids/girl-copes-with-anxiety-about-scoliosis.html)

Comment: Current AmE may be a lot "slacker" than BrE in this respect, but certainly that *as long as = since* sense would not generally be endorsed on my side of the pond. For Brits, it's *as long as = **so** long as = **provided = if***. In some contexts there would be a *lot* of difference (*since* implies that the condition *has been fulfilled*, which would sometimes be presumptuous if the matter is still in abeyance).

Comment: In AmE, I would take “**for** as long as” to mean “since.” Without the _for_ I agree with Fumble.

Comment: As a speaker of AmE, I don't think the sense of "since" as given that this conditional statement is true (or while this conditional statement is true) is accurately captured by *seeing that* very well unless *seeing that* is understood in a highly nuanced way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AmE:  As long as has the following connotations:

1)  Provided or If or *since* (not time related) - see note below:

> *As long as* you use the term correctly, people will understand you.

Note:  Since is usually used for a past condition that is now fulfilled.   So, it's not an exact fit in meaning to as long as.

**As requested in comments** I will attempt to expand upon *as long as* vs. *since*.

The easiest way to compare these is to compare their synonyms: if vs. because.

If you think of *as long as* as being a fancy way of saying *if*, then you will see its usage to be a way of constructing a conditional.

> If you go to the store, we will have food for dinner tonight.
>
> As long as you go to the store, we will have food for dinner tonight.

If you think of *since* being a fancy way of saying *because*, you will see it is a fulfilled condition.

> Because you went to the store, we have food for dinner tonight.
>
> Since you went to the store, we have food for dinner tonight.

This is why I was willing to include *since* on the list of connotations.  It's not an exact fit of meaning, but they are closely related in a cause-and-effect type of relationship.

2)  Comparions of length

> The new trail was not *as long as* the old trail.

3)  Since (when used with For)

> For *as long as* I can remember, I have been fascinated by photography.

All three of these have currency in American English.

1&3 are less formal to my ear.

For formal writing I would use *provided* for #1.

> *Provided* you use the proper terminology, you will be understood.

I would likely avoid #3 altogether in formal writing, preferring an exact date range where possible.

Otherwise, if not possible I would use *from* or *since*:

> *From childhood onward*, he showed a propensity toward the cello that would flourish into a career.

Comment: David, the only thing is you seem to be considering the conjunction "since" in the sense "during the period subsequent to the time" as in "He hasn't been home since [=for as long as] he graduated", or in the sense "continuously from the time when" as in "they have been friends since [=ever since/for as long as] they were in grade school"; whereas what I mean is "since" in the sense "seeing that/considering/inasmuch as" as in "since [=as long as] I won't tell you about it" or "since [=as long as] you're already here, you might as well stay".

Comment: I mean "Since [=as long as] you're not interested, I won't tell you about it".

Comment: @nourishedgourmet Case #1 is the way you asking about.  This is the since/provided sense you are asking about in your last example. It is used in AmE. But, for some reason (don't ask why) it sounds strange to say "As long as you're not interested,". It sounds like you're being facetious.

Comment: @nourishedgourmet Since actually sounds strange there, too. I would use If in that situation. If you're not interested, I won't tell you.

Comment: The only thing is "since" -- unlike "if" and "provided" -- implies that the condition has been fulfilled.

Comment: @nourishedgourmet Since does imply that the condition has been fulfilled. Yes.  It is better at conveying that sense than as long as.  Since you didn't go to the store, I can't cook dinner.  As long as would be a bad fit there.

Comment: Since is a conditional in the past. As long as is a conditional in the present.  Does that help?

Comment: As long as you went to the store, I can cook dinner.  It's not exactly the same meaning. Just related.

Comment: Also note that some people object to using *since* to mean *because.*

Comment: And for some of these, *so long as* may sound better.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I fully agree!

Comment: @DavidM So how does "As long as you went to the store, I can cook dinner" differ meaningwise from "Since you went to the store, I can cook dinner" and from "As you went to the store, I can cook dinner"? Also, I wish you could tell the story to "as long as" in the sense "since/seeing that". How and at what point in the evolution of AE did this idiomatic conjunction move from the respective senses of "during the time that" and "on condition that" -- which it actually still carries -- to the subtler sense "since, seeing that"?

Comment: @DavidM I'm all the more curious to know the story to it aa "as long as has apparently no currency or grammaticality in BE http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/long. And so, if as a student I had ventured "as long as" for "since (=seeing that)", it would have been considered patently wrong.

Comment: @nourishedgourmet The answer to your erudite question is:  it's hard to explain. I would say, there is no actual currency to the usage directly to mean since. But, they are closely related. So, were you to use one for the other I would say:  not patently wrong, but a bit off. Make sense?  I wish I could give a better answer but that would take time. Perhaps this evening I will edit my answer to include all of this for you.

Comment: @nourishedgourmet I must say, that apart from your sometimes mildly incorrect usage of idioms your English is fabulous.  It gives me great pleasure to try to answer your questions. Unfortunately, there are questions that are beyond the scope of my knowledge.

Comment: @DavidM Thank you! Do you know of any one in ELU that might be able to answer these questions?

Comment: @NourishedGourmet I would suggest that you keep posting questions. Whoever can properly answer will. But, I would recommend avoiding the free dictionary.  It lets a lot of really questionable usages slide!

Comment: @DavidM Sure, no problem. So what online AE dictionary do you recommend that I use?

Comment: @NourishedGourmet www.m-w.com; www.dictionary.com  Both are free, and significantly better than wiktionary, or free online dictionary.